# Gravitational anomaly: When these occur?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity, path-integral, quantum-anomalies

Consider the partition function for a quantum-gravitational theory

$$Z=\int D[\Xi]e^{iS(\Xi)}$$

Here, $\Xi$ is a configuration variables for space time; this variable must not necessarily be the metric and Levi-Civita connection.

The action $S(\Xi)$ is General Relativity, but reformulated in other kind of topological structures. For an anomaly, it holds $S(\Xi) = S(\Xi')$ for a diffeomorphism $\Xi \mapsto \Xi'$, but it holds $D[\Xi] \neq D[\Xi']$. What is the general condition for an invariant action, but non-invariant measure factor? Are there examples where this happens?

Comment: A canonical reference for gravitational anomalies would be the paper by Alvarez-Gaume and Witten. I'm not sure one can improve on the original discussion usefully in the space of an answer for a question this broad - you could try to be a bit more specific in what you want to know about gravitational anomalies.